# NodeJS and Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins

As part of the setup for building my environment for a job in Jenkins, I have checked the

```
Provide Node & npm bin/ folder to PATH
```

At the moment it defaults to `Installation NodeJS`

When running a job it gets to this point

```
$ /Users/jenkins/.jenkins/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/NodeJS/bin/npm install -g grunt-cli
```

but returns

```
env: node: No such file or directory
```

When manually going to the `npm` folder I cannot `cd` into it but a `ls -la` outputs

```
npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

What is happening here, and why am I getting the error?

Comment: Did you configure NodeJS installation in 'Global Tool Configuration' ?